# Write a regular expression to capture a substring from html

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I have to find a particular pattern from html text using regular expression

For example:

my string is

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td><p align="justify"><u>Counsel appeared</u></p><p align="justify"><a name="COUNSEL" id="COUNSEL"></a>K. P. Garg CA<b>for the Appellant</b>.: A. K. Monga, Sr. DR <b>for theRespondent</b></p><p align="justify"><b><u><a name="JUDGE" id="JUDGE"></a>R. P.TOLANI, JM.</u></b></p><p align="justify">testing</p>..........and so on
```

and I want to remove a `<p align="justify"><u>Counsel appeared</u></p><p align="justify"><a name="COUNSEL" id="COUNSEL"></a>K. P. Garg CA<b>for the Appellant</b>.: A. K. Monga, Sr. DR <b>for theRespondent</b></p>` this portion from html text. The text enclosed in the the html tags is dynamic.

For this I have written following regular expression

```
gsub(/<p align="justify"><u>counsel appeared<\/u><\/p><p align="justify"><a name="counsel" id="counsel"><\/a>.*<b>.*<\/b><\/p>/i, '')
```

but its removing the whole text from ``counsel appeared</u></p> till end.

So how I remove a particular portion from the above html string?
Can anyone help me in modifying my regular expression ?

Comment: I don't mean to be *that guy*, but maybe you should use an html parser instead of relying on regex. Take a look at this famous SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern:

`<p\s+?align\s*?=\s*?"justify">\s*?<u>\s*?counsel appeared\s*?<\/u>\s*?<\/p>\s*?<p\s+?align\s*?=\s*?"justify">\s*?<a\s+?name\s*?=\s*?"counsel"\s+?id\s*?=\s*?"counsel">\s*?<\/a>.*?<b>.*?<\/b>\s*?<\/p>`